# Examples of $\kappa$-Fréchet-Urysohn spaces.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

We say that

> A space $X$ is $\kappa$-Fréchet-Urysohn at a point $x\in X$, if whenever $x\in\overline{U}$, where $U$ is a regular open subset of $X$, some 
>   sequence of points of $U$ converges to $x$.

I'm looking for some examples of $\kappa$-Fréchet-Urysohn space. I guess it is not true that every compact Hausdorff space is a $\kappa$-Fréchet-Urysohn But how about compact Hausdorff homogeneous spaces?

Answer (score 2):

**It may be helpful for you:**

Every first countable space $X$ is always $\kappa$-Fréchet-Urysohn spaces.

> **Proof:** As $X$ is first countable, then $\overline{U}$ is also first countable. For any $x\in \overline{U}$, as $U$ is dense in $\overline{U}$, then there exists a sequence of $U$ such converges to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

What examples are you looking for?

I think, for some exotic examples you should search Engelking’s “General Topology” (on Frechet-Urysohn spaces) and part 10 “Generalized metric spaces”
of the “[Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology](http://webfile.ru/6475714)”.

Comment: I'm looking for specific examples. And my goal is to show that any κ-Fréchet-Urysohn group is a moscow but it is not true that every κ-Fréchet-Urysohn space is a moscow space. For example, $\alpha D(\tau)$ (one-point compactification of the discrete space $D$) having this property.

Comment: @TXC: And what is about a free (abelian) group over $\alpha D(\tau)$?

Comment: I am not sure but i think $F\big( \alpha D(\tau)\big)$ is a moscow group. $\alpha D(\tau)$ is compact then $F\big( \alpha D(\tau)\big)$ has countable cellularity and Every paratopological group $G$ with countable cellularity is a moscow space.